# Sql server 2012 process reaches 2 GB of memory in one hour if open Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I have strange situation with Sql Server 2012.

If I open Management Studio 2012 (11.0.2100.60) and make some query on a table, the process `sqlservr.exe` reaches 2 GB of RAM memory in one hour. It still increases even I closed management studio application. So, every time I have to restart service in order to free up memory.

Question: It is possible to solve it or I have to wait for a service pack ?

Below is the proof:

[image]

Comment: The name of the tab cut off. Which Memory tab is that? Are you sure it's RAM?

Comment: Is `Memory (private working set)`

Comment: If it's private working set, then it's providing a meaningless number if your system isn't under memory pressure. Windows will try to give every process as much RAM as it possibly can if that memory isn't needed for anything else. (What else can it do with the memory?)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you turn off IntelliSense, the memory consumption subsides dramatically, and the software becomes much more responsive. To turn it off, go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Transact-SQL -> IntelliSense, and un-check the box. Save your work and re-start the SSMS.

The major drawback is that you will loose both IntelliSense and Code Outlining. Quite a bummer, but at least you can leave the SSMS open for days without problems.